# Oracle Table or view doesn't exist

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

i'm trying to deplay a java application to weblogic, it uses oracle as database, this is in the log of the application

[image]

but the thing is, it does exist, and it has data

[image]

so, any ideas of what's going on here? (sorry, i can't show some names of tables, schemas, or classes)

also, the jndi is configured properly, the test query works fine

thanks

Comment: What user is weblogic connecting as? Is it the same schema as the table? If not, did you grant SELECT on that table to the weblogic user?

Comment: it's the same user i'm using to connect with the sql developer

Comment: Option 1 is that there is a difference between the connection set up in JNDI and in SQL Developer (you're connecting as a different user or to a different database).  Option 2 is that you're enabling a non-default role in your SQL Developer session that gives you access to the table.  Option 3 is that the query in your Java application isn't actually what you're showing in SQL Developer because you've got a typo.  I would wager that the issue is Option 1.